# Need help reducing execution time for scraping dynamic content

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently scraping dynamic content from a website using Selenium (chrome), but the automated browser is taking way too long to process. (There is a "view more" button on a profile page which I am scraping, and it only loads 5 posts per each click) There is no other way to access these "hidden" posts without clicking the "view more" button and it take way too long to manually click the button in order to retrieve posts from a while ago. Any idea on how I can speed up this process?

URL: https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/5045

Comment: if page has API then use it. If you can rewrite it without Seleniu. If you have to use Selenium then run with option `--headless` - it will run without displaying window and it doesn't need to render all on screen.

Comment: Without knowing the URL it's hard to see how to speed up things. Look in developer tools where the page is making requests, notice the URLs and maybe you can query those URLs directly.

Comment: @AndrejKesely sorry, i've just added the url.
https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/5045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the page, there's URL which accepts `offset` and `limit` parameter. With this you can get many messages at once. You could put this into the loop, increasing `offset` parameter and get all the messages without selenium:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    url = 'https://r1.community.samsung.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/5045'

    user_id = url.split('/')[-1]
    posts_url = 'https://r1.community.samsung.com/plugins/custom/samsung/samsungelamer2/custom.profile-activity?type=posts&offset={}&limit={}&currentUser={}'

    offset = 0
    limit = 100

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(posts_url.format(offset, limit, user_id)).text, 'lxml')

    for i, (subject, message_body) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('.message-subject'), soup.select('.lia-message-body-content')), 1):
        print('Message {}'.format(i))
        print('Subject:\n', subject.text.strip())
        print('Message body:\n', message_body.text.strip())
        print('*' * 120)
```

Prints:

```
    Message 1
    Subject:
     안드로이드 Q Beta 프리뷰 5 새로운 제스쳐
    Message body:
     안드로이드 Q O ...

    ...and so on.
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks so much, saved me so much time!
This is just a follow-up question for scraping other content but, what are some ways to scrape multiple pages (eg. some_url_/page/1, some_url/page/2, etc.) without requesting content from each url?

Comment: @Joonie Without requesting content? You need to have something to scrape from, so request to each URL is necessary (unless all the content is already present in page, which in majority cases is not)